# Deconstruct/decode Websocket frames like Google Chrome does

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm connecting to a website via websocket connection *(client to server)*, I know how to encode the data and write it to the server *(using the `net` module in node.js)* but when I'm reading the data back I get odd characters in front of the important data, like if I'm suppose to get:

```
// Data needed on the left and data I'm receiving from websocket on the right
'inited\r\n' -> '�inited\r\n'
'n:2\r\n'     -> '�n:2\r\n'
```

This is how I am getting the data from the server

```
Klass.prototype.connect = function(){
    // this.port is equal to 8080 and the exact server varys, but it's not that important anyways since the problem is decoding the data properly.
    var that    = this;
    var buffer    = "";
    this.socket = new net.createConnection(this.port, this.server);
    this.socket
    .on("connect", function(){
        that.sendHandshake(); // just sends a standard client to server handshake
    })
    .on("data", function(recv){
        // .split('\r\n\r\n').join('\r\n') needed to separate the server handshake from the data I am trying to parse
        buffer += recv.toString('utf-8').split('\r\n\r\n').join('\r\n'); 
        while (buffer){
            var offset = buffer.indexOf('\r\n');
            if (offset < 0) 
                return;
            var msg  = buffer.slice(0, offset);
            // parseMsg(msg)
            buffer = buffer.slice(offset + 3);  
        }       
    });

};
```

I am probably doing a lot of things improperly in the code above, but I'm not quite sure how to do it exactly so that is the best I got for now.

Problem is I don't know how to remove the mystery/special characters. Sometimes there is only 1 mystery/special character, but other times there is multiple ones depending on the data but they are never after the important data I need to check.

When I use Google Chrome and view the data on through *tools->JavaScript console->network tab* and find the websocket stream I'm looking for Google parses it correctly. I know it's possible since Google Chrome shows the correct frames, how do I deconstruct/decode the data so I can view the correct frames on the terminal?

I don't really need it in a particular language as long as it works I should be able to port it, but I would prefer examples/answers in *node.js* since that is the programming language I am using to connect to the server.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `net` module for web sockets, use https://www.npmjs.org/package/ws

Comment: @generalhenry Will the `ws` module work for client to server connection on a specific port, lets say port `8080` or maybe `1800`? If so can you post a small example as an answer and if it works I'll mark it as best. Thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: What are those characters? Even if you cannot print them out, please get their charcodes.

Comment: @Bergi They vary, but usually if not always the first character of the received data has a char code value of 65533 but depending on the data    it can have 65533 as the first char code value, then the next one may be something completely random like a char code value of 125, 127, etc.

Comment: That doesn't look very random actually, but more like a forgotten padding. Please show us your code

Comment: @Bergi Forgotten Padding? Maybe lack of. I'm not decoding anything from the server that is pretty much raw data. I'll update the question real quick to show how I am reading the data from the socket shortly.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the question to show how I am getting the received data from the socket. Hopefully that will be helpful.

Comment: @generalhenry After looking into the ws module more it is exactly what I need thank you I already have it working, but I'd rather not answer my own question so if you can post an answer that shows an example websocket client using that module I would be more than happy to accept it as the best answer.